# GMS Marker fixed to center of map in Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How would one ensure that a GMS marker remains fixed on the centre of the map only allowing the map to be dragged but not the marker?

Thanks

Comment: Just add the marker over the map at the center (which is what Saqib suggests).. there is no reason to put extra stress on recalculating the coordinate of the marker to keep it centered

Answer (score 0):

First get center position from CLLocationManager & than put marker using GMS Marker.

In order to get current location conform to CLLcationManagerDelegate & use the following function to get your location coordinates:

```
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = manager.location else {
            return
        }
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        // place marker to center of the map
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add vertical and horizontal constraints to align marker view.

```
let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: YourMarkerView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.YourMapView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: YourMarkerView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.YourMapView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.YourMapView.addConstraint(xConstraint)
self.YourMapView.addConstraint(yConstraint)
```

Also make sure you have constraints added to YourMapView. (You can add them in storyboard.)